# CodeIgniter 4 API with Angular 10: $this->request->getPost() is always empty

Tags: angular, codeigniter, post

I am rewriting my CI3 app to CI4 and I'm facing a lot of issues, actually.

Right now, I have a working API built on CI4, and the get request works great with the Angular frontend and Postman, but the post request only works with Postman.

This is my Routes.php:

```
$routes->options('(:any)', 'LoginController::options');
$routes->get('/api/login', 'LoginController::index');
$routes->post('/api/login/login', 'LoginController::login');
```

Here is part of my LoginController:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controllers;

    use CodeIgniter\Controller;
    use App\Models\LoginModel;
    use CodeIgniter\HTTP\Response;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {

    protected $login_model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->login_model = new LoginModel();
    }

    public function options(): Response
    {
        return $this->response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK); // Status code for CORS
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return;
    }

    public function login()
    {

    try {
        $data = $this->request->getPost();

        $username = $data['username'];
        $password = $data['password'];

        list($user, $status) = $this->login_model->login($username, $password);
    }
    [...]
```

And this is part of the Angular service, that sends the request:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };
    
    let body = {
         username: username,
         password: password
    }

    return this.http.post<any>(
      `${this.API_URL}/login/login`, 
      body,
      httpOptions
    ).pipe [...]
```

On Postman, everything works like a charm. With Angluar I hit the endpoint and while debugging I can see that the login function is being called, but `$this->request->getPost();` is always empty.

If I changed back the endpoint to CI3, without changing the Angular code, it works.

Has anyone faced anything similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must try $this->request->getJSON() , it works for me.

Comment: It works! I don't know who marked this answers as negative. Any way, another option is to use: file_get_contents("php://input");